# Excel VBA - Error in Updating Chart Scale

Tags: vba, excel

i found a way to update chart for the maximum and minimum scale. I tweaked the code to find the value for the maximum scale which is the last row. Below is the code:

```
Sub ScaleAxes()

Dim LastRow, LastRow2 As Long

  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .MaximumScale = LastRow
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
  End With
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .MaximumScale = LastRow2
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

However i getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Im not sure which part my code is wrong. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Which line throws the error ? You are missing a worksheet reference by the looks of it - `.Cells` is not a property of the `Axes` class.

Comment: LastRow = .Cells(.Row.Count..... line is the one throwing the error message

Answer (score 0):

`.Cells` is not a property of the `Axes` class and within your `With` statement it reads that you want to access that property of `Axes` when, it is likely you are trying to get `Cells` property of the worksheet that the chart is on. To get a reference to the worksheet you can use:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveChart.Parent.Parent
```

And then use the `ws` reference when you get the `LastRow` value:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()

    Dim LastRow, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveChart.Parent.Parent

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .MaximumScale = LastRow
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
    End With
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        LastRow2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .MaximumScale = LastRow2
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The code is working but only for the minimum scale which is the first value but not the last value (max scale). In the link below, you can see the initial graph:

[link]http://imgur.com/a/dCz92

Thus i need to make the graph full scale. Thats where the code comes in. The code above manage to set the minimum scale but not max scale as the pic below:

[link]http://imgur.com/a/NIJqG

Comment: Its not possible to understand how your code works re setting the axes with no source data etc. Your question was about fixing a totally different error...

Comment: Hi Robin. Here is the link for the data file. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c7fbe8ffd72778942d35c907fc78749d20170301064051/22f747924a806349a475b0ad83373f2420170301064051/e64cab

Comment: Hi Jeeva - normally you ask a question about something and if someone answers then great - you had your question answered. If you have a second question then you should start another post. It considered polite to just restrict yourself to one-thread-one-issue. best of luck.